# Execute logic on place order

Tags: magento-1.9, module, checkout, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I created new payment method module, bud I need to execute my logic (send data to our server, handle response etc.) when user clicks **Place order** button. Is there a way to execute my logic when placing order? I saw some people using events, but I have some issues using them and I still hope there must be easier way to do so, because it is quite obvious that I want to execute some action if I define new payment method module.

Comment: magento version?

Comment: Version 1.9.2.4 But if it is possible, we need some permanent solution. All I need is to understand where is place order event called and how to modify that. If you have a link for good magento doc, it would be great.

Comment: i added the solution for redirect after place order with observer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your are using mag-1 then there is method in your Payment Model. add this method after placing the order this will redirect on their add your logic.

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
{
//when you click on place order you will be redirected on this url, if you don't want this action remove this method
return Mage::getUrl('test/standard/redirect', array('_secure' => true));
}
```

for reference you can see

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/

if you don't want to use this method then use this event

```
sales_order_save_after
```

Comment: Thank you. I used this method, but we changed logic a bit and also, we do not want to redirect, so I am searching for _no-redirect_ way. We just send our request in background and only redirect to success page if everything was successful. I do not really understand the workflow of Magento, but I know that I do not want to change core files.

Comment: @JakubGruber This is not core file it will be your module file and i am not saying to change any core file.

Comment: I know. I just state that I found some core-modify solutions and I cannot use them. I know that getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() is called after Place order, but I do not want to redirect user. He either stays on page in case of problems or he is redirected to success page. All I need is method similar to getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl that is also called in that process.

Comment: @JakubGruber then it is better to use event `sales_order_save_after`

Comment: So, if I understand that correctly: There is no way to do that without event? Anyway thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly, I cannot give your positive feedback because a lack of reputation.

Comment: @JakubGruber without redirection better way is event.